# I want to install http_sub_module on windows

Tags: nginx

How can I add the **http_sub_module** module in Nginx on the windows platform?
Want to redirect the relative URLs in Nginx. Currently I'm not able to redirect the URLs.

Answer (score 0):

As suggested by [the documentation of `ngx_http_sub_module`](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_sub_module.html),
the module is not built by default:

> This module is not built by default, it should be enabled with the --with-http_sub_module configuration parameter.

To have this module enabled, the `--with-http_sub_module` configuration parameter has to be used **when building Nginx itself**.
It is impossible to install the module afterwards.

To see if your installation of Nginx has this module enabled,
check if `--with-http_sub_module` is present in the output of `nginx -V`.
If not, you may have to build Nginx yourself with the parameter enabled.